# Android refactor URL onClick button

Tags: java, android, url, button, android-activity

I want to make an android app where when the user of the app clicks a button, it should go to the IP-address of a RaspBerry PI. This Pi is located on the network itself and has a static IP, but it should be specified by the user once.

I've got a TextField where the user can put the IP-address of the Pi. This should be stored in SharedPreferences. Here's the code for this part:

```
public void save(View view) {
    editor.putString("homeIP", textHomeIP.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    editor.putString("PiIP", textPiIP.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    piIP = textPiIP.getText().toString();
    homeIP = textHomeIP.getText().toString();

    makeURL();

    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    finish();
}
```

This method runs when clicked on the save button. The class extends the MainActivity and is opened with the settings xml when the settings button is clicked. For some reason in the MainActivity the URL cannot be changed. Here's the method to change the URL

```
protected void makeURL()
{
    if(mSocket != null)
    {
        mSocket.disconnect();
    }

    try
    {
        url = new URL("http://" + piIP);
        Log.d("URL", url.toString());
    }
    catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {}

    try
    {
        mSocket = IO.socket(url.toString(), opts);
    }
    catch (java.net.URISyntaxException e)
    {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Cant initialize socket: " + e.toString());
    }

    mSocket.connect();
    mSocket.on("detection-start", detectionStart);
    mSocket.on("detection-end", detectionEnd);
}
```

The socket does actually connect but the URL stays the same for some reason. I run this method in the onCreate and initiate piIP before that.

Here's onCreate method:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ipActivity = new IPActivity();
    ipActivity.execute();

    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    notificationSettings();

    //connectionChanger = new ConnectionChangeReceiver();

    sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    editor = sharedPref.edit();

    homeIP = sharedPref.getString("homeIP", "localhost");
    piIP = sharedPref.getString("PiIP", "localhost");

    Log.d("Pi IP", piIP);

    makeURL();
}
```

And at last here's the openBrowser() method

```
public void openBrowser(View view)
{
    makeURL();
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.toString()));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Can someone please tell me why the URL is not changed when the settings are saved?

Comment: can you elaborate: "The socket does actually connect but the URL stays the same for some reason"?

Comment: The user socket connects to the user's given IP address and can receive events from the server. The URL however still links to localhost

Comment: do you see any error in logcat? I see you put Log.d in makeURL

Comment: No errors at all. When i save the settings, piIP is the in settings given ip, but the url is still localhost

Comment: check your editor.commit() success by using boolean isSuccess= editor.commit();

Comment: In the makeURL() method the Log.d(URL, url.toString()) says: 04-13 23:06:23.940 7705-7705/stenden.whoisthere D/URL: http://*right url*:8000, so it basically works until that point, but when the url is being clicked it still goes to localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using getPreferences instead of getSharedPreferences. It fixed the problem of creating the URL. I made the subclasses classes on their own and let de ip addresses load via getSharedPreferences.